# Drawing Numbers from Gaussian

Tags: probability, statistics

I am fairly new to statistics, and currently working through some practice problems. One problem asks:

> What is the probability, that when drawing $n$ points $x_i ...x_n$, that these  are in the upper half plane, given that the points are normally distributed $\ x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, Id) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I seem to lack some intuition for this problem. I would like to say that the chance of selecting a single point from the upper half plane is $50\%$ due to the symmetry around the origin of the distribution, but I am not sure if this is correct.

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly right, change of selecting each point in the upper half plane is $0.5$, so a chance of selecting both $x_1$ and $x_2$ there is $0.5^2$, etc. What is the chance of selecting them all in the upper half plane?

Comment: Simply extending that line of thinking, I'd say the chance of selecting all in the upper plane is $0.5^N$.

Comment: @ABCCHEM Exactly :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that the x-position and y-position of the points are independent (since the covariance matrix is a scaled diagonal matrix), you can treat the y-position as a univariate Gaussian distribution. Since the mean is 0 and the Gaussian distribution is symmetric about the mean, you can then claim that $P\{y_{x_i} < 0\}  = P\{y_{x_i} > 0\} = 1$ (since those events form a partition).